# What are the first three values for the following recursive sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

$a_0 = 3$

$a_n = (a_{n-1})^2 + (a_{n-2})^2 +\cdots + (a_0)^2$ for all integers $n\geq 1$.

Would that mean $a_1 = a_0^2 = 9$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. And $a_2=a_1^2+a_0^2=9^2+3^2=90$.

Comment: Yes, you've got the correct value for $a_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Cheers! Oh, and just wanted to clarify that by first three values, that would just go up to $a_2$ only, right? It wouldn't include $a_3$?

Comment: @SammieG: I’d interpret it to mean $a_0,a_1$, and $a_2$, but I can imagine someone interpreting it as the first three values not yet given, i.e., $a_1,a_2$, and $a_3$.